# event hub capture data backlog

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-rest-api

I would like to capture the metric for and EventHub, capture data backlog . Is there a rest api to get the reault . I am developing a .Net application to monitor azure resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Metrics [Restapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) or the .NET SDK. Read more about metrics in Azure Monitor [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-metrics-azure-monitor)

Github Sample for [monitor-dotnet-metrics-api](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api)

Comment: getting not found error when i call this getapi "https://management.azure.com*******************/resourceGroups/*******/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2015-01-01"

Comment: i am looking for the output of a CaptureBacklog metric(count) in a rest API

Comment: Keep looking @jubi